# Запятая перед И: "Они... не захватывают власть, а приходят к ней волею избирателей(,) и свое право на управление доказывают честным трудом"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Они никогда не захватывают власть, а приходят к ней волею избирателей(,) и свое право на управление и руководство великолепно доказывают честным и самоотверженным трудом

Нужна ли тут запятая перед И?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У нас простое предложение, осложненное однородными сказуемыми, относящимися к общему субъекту, связь между которыми отражается на письме разными союзами: *они не захватывают, **а** приходят **и** доказывают*. Следовательно, перед союзом И запятая не нужна: "*они никогда не захватывают власть, а приходят к ней волею избирателей и свое право на управление и руководство великолепно доказывают честным и самоотверженным трудом*".

Answer (score 0):

перед И ставится не запятая, а тире:"Они не захватывают, а приходят по воле... - и свое право...доказывают...". Вторая часть предложения является следствием первого, т.е. избиратели выбрали, а следовательно, избранные доказывают свое право и руководство трудом.