# Запятая перед И в предложении: [Подлежащее] не [1-е сказуемое], а [2-е сказуемое](,) и [3-е сказуемое]

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены

Это вопрос возник в связи с другим вопросом: [Запятая перед И: "Они... не захватывают власть, а приходят к ней волею избирателей(,) и свое право на управление доказывают честным трудом"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6966/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%98)

Меня интересует случай, когда первому сказуемому противопоставлено только второе. Рассмотрим, например, такое предложение:

> Он не уклоняется от налогов, а платит их регулярно(,) и свой бизнес ведет честно.

Я думаю, что нужна запятая перед группой третьего сказуемого, но не знаю, как это обосновать. Нет ли такого правила, что если только второе сказуемое противопоставлено первому, то группа второго сказуемого должна обособляться?

А если так:

> Он не уклоняется от налогов, а платит их регулярно(,) и честно ведет свой бизнес.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, уважаемый М_Г, вряд ли Вы найдёте обоснование этой запятой при однородных членах.

*Он не уклоняется от налогов, а платит их регулярно и свой бизнес ведет честно.*

Здесь явно в группу объединяются первые два однородных сказуемых, а уже **группа**  соединена **с одиночным** третьим сказуемым  неповторяющимся соединительным союзом И - запятой нет.

Однако если Вам хочется поставить запятую, значит, Вы воспринимаете часть  **"и свой бизнес ведет честно"** как присоединительную конструкцию. Вот если союз присоединительный, то перед ним запятую имеете право поставить, но тогда это будет авторская пунктуация. Если Вы автор - пожалуйста, а если просто должны расставить запятые, то должны ставить их по правилам.

Answer (score 1):

Обычная история.

**Этот вопрос не получил в лингвистике однозначного решения.** Поэтому по стандартным правилам запятая не нужна, что соответствует требованиям  **школьной практики.**

Если же вы пишете статью для журнала, то современный подход к синтаксису русского языка может быть учтен.

Чем **больше степень спаянности сказуемых, тем ближе они к однородному ряду.** При большой коммуникативной расчлененности и самостоятельности частей, содержащих сказуемые, такое предложение можно считать сложным, а **паузу** между частыми предложения, особенно распространенного, **желательно обозначить.**

(1) Он не уклоняется от налогов, а платит их регулярно, и свой бизнес (он) ведет честно.

**Для бОльшей расчлененности можно добавить наречие:**

(2) Он не уклоняется от налогов, а платит их регулярно, и **поэтому**  бизнес свой   ведет честно.

Сравним:

(3) **Он не уклоняется от налогов, а регулярно платит их и   ведет свой бизнес честно.**

Это предложение ближе к простому.